# ¿Cómo inserto este comando de SQLServer en código de VB.Net? (explico)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Quiero crear una base de datos y el código para crearala es este:

```
ConexionSQL As New SqlConnection(CadenaDeConexion()) 
  ConexionSQL.Open()
  ComandoCrearSQL = New SqlCommand("AQUI IRIA EL COMANDO", ConexionSQL)
  ComandoCrearSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Estos comandos crean la base de datos:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Datos v7.5]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'Datos v7.5', FILENAME = N'C:\Datos v7.5.mdf' , SIZE = 72960KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [Certificados] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
( NAME = N'Certificados', FILENAME = N'C:\Certificados' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED), 
 FILEGROUP [Fotos] CONTAINS FILESTREAM  DEFAULT
( NAME = N'Fotos', FILENAME = N'C:\Fotos' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Datos v7.5_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Datos v7.5.ldf' , SIZE = 20096KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [Datos v7.5].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Datos v7.5] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
```

La consulta es cómo puedo poner todas esas líneas en el código de arriba, donde dice "AQUI IRIA EL COMANDO". U otra forma de crear todo en un solo bloque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo podrias hacer de esta forma

```
Using ConexionSQL As New SqlConnection(CadenaDeConexion())
    ConexionSQL.Open()

    Dim ComandoCrearSQL As SqlCommand = ConexionSQL.CreateCommand()

    ' Concatena todas las sentencias SQL en una sola cadena
    Dim sqlScript As String = "
        CREATE DATABASE [Datos v7.5]
        CONTAINMENT = NONE
        ON  PRIMARY 
        ( NAME = N'Datos v7.5', FILENAME = N'C:\Datos v7.5.mdf' , SIZE = 72960KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ), 
        FILEGROUP [Certificados] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
        ( NAME = N'Certificados', FILENAME = N'C:\Certificados' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED), 
        FILEGROUP [Fotos] CONTAINS FILESTREAM  DEFAULT
        ( NAME = N'Fotos', FILENAME = N'C:\Fotos' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
        LOG ON 
        ( NAME = N'Datos v7.5_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Datos v7.5.ldf' , SIZE = 20096KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
        WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
        GO

        IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
        begin
        EXEC [Datos v7.5].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
        end
        GO

        ALTER DATABASE [Datos v7.5] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
        GO
    "

    ComandoCrearSQL.CommandText = sqlScript
    ComandoCrearSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

De esta forma se concatenaron las sentencias SQL en una sola cadena, ejecutas el bloque con ExecuteNonQuery()

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias.